# how to fix this dict and postgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.3

i just want to update my keys,values from my dict

this is for updating PostgreSQL using python dict

```
data ={

        'created_by':'obama',
        'last_updated_by':'nandu',
        'effective_from':'2019-12-30',
        'effective_to':'2017-12-30'
        }

lst= list()
lst1 = list()

for key,value in data.items():    
    lst.append(key)
    lst1.append(value)

keys = tuple(lst)
values = tuple(lst1)

update = "UPDATE table_name SET %s = %s where name = 'kumar'"
cur.execute(update,(keys,values))
```

i want to set keys as field name and values as values 
but i am getting the field names(keys) as string
so i am getting syntax error

Comment: You don't need temp variables of `lst`, `lst1`, `keys` and `values`.
You may use `assignments = ['%s = %s' %(key, value) for key,value in data.items()]` `set_clause = 'SET %s' % assignments` `update = "UPDATE table_name %s where name = 'kumar'" % set_clause`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tuples for SET. Best is to loop over the dict and set each key one at the time:

```
data ={'created_by':'obama',
       'last_updated_by':'nandu',
       'effective_from':'2019-12-30',
       'effective_to':'2017-12-30',
}

for key, value in data.items():    
    update = "UPDATE table_name SET %s = %s where name = 'kumar'"
    cur.execute(update,(key, value))
```

or following the suggestion using f-strings

```
data ={'created_by':'obama',
       'last_updated_by':'nandu',
       'effective_from':'2019-12-30',
       'effective_to':'2017-12-30',
}

arguments = ','.join([f'{key}=\'{val}\'' for key, val in data.items()])

update = f"UPDATE table_name SET {arguments} where name = 'kumar'"
cur.execute(update)
```